# Function convert to MD5 not working inside a function SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to flag some data hashed in md5 inside a function.

I have the table BDM_TMP_MAIL_HARD contains some mail. I need to match some mail of another table in md5 with the mail of this table.

**MY TABLE WITH MAIL IN MD5**

| EMAILMD5 | MATCH |
| --- | --- |
| ***8747e564eb53cb2f1dcb9aae0779c2aa*** | **1** |
| 4545e564eqsqdsb2f1dcb46ae0779c2aa | 0 |

**TABLE BDM_TMP_MAIL_HARD**

| MAIL | TO_MD5(MAIL) |
| --- | --- |
| exemple@gmail.com | ***8747e564eb53cb2f1dcb9aae0779c2aa*** |
| example2@sfr.fr | 368e564eqsq4242f1dc344242d79c2aa |

I use a function, taken from another package, called 'to_md5' that converts the mail to md5. So, I will use this function on the table BDM_TMP_MAIL_HARD.

The problem is when I execute the function, **it never ends**.

I've done multiple tests, the select count is correct and if I try to do the update without function, it works. If I execute the function without the to_md5(), it works.

Just if I put inside the function to_md5, the function never ends.

Why does the function work without the to_md5() function?

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET MATCH =
    FILTRE_MARKET_OP.FILTRE_V1_MARKET_OP_MD5(lower(emailMD5));
```

```
FUNCTION FILTRE_V1_MARKET_OP_MD5(mail IN varchar) RETURN NUMBER IS   
    hard number;
    mail_filtre  varchar2(300);
BEGIN
    hard := 0;
    mail_filtre := mail;
    
    SELECT count(*) INTO hard FROM BDM_TMP_MAIL_HARD
    WHERE  EMAIL IS NOT NULL
    AND    to_md5(email) = mail_filtre;

    IF hard >= 1 THEN
        hard := 1;
        GOTO FIN;       
    END IF;
    
    <<FIN>>  
    RETURN hard;
        
END FILTRE_V1_MARKET_OP_MD5;
```

Otherwise, cause that's not working, i do manually the update like that:

```
update MY_TABLE set MATCH = 1
where  lower(emailMD5) in
       ( select to_md5(lower(EMAIL))
         from   BDM_TMP_MAIL_HARD
         where  EMAIL is not null )
and    emailMD5 is not null;
```

and this is my custom md5 function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION to_MD5 (str IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    v_checksum VARCHAR2(32);
BEGIN
    v_checksum := LOWER( RAWTOHEX( UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW( sys.dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5(input_string => str) ) ) );
    RETURN v_checksum;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
        RAISE;
END to_MD5;
```

Comment: How many rows do you have in your `optima.BDM_TMP_MAIL_HARD` table?

Comment: Maybe you need function-based index on BDM_TMP_MAIL_HARD

Comment: 500 k more or less

Comment: @leftjoin  to_md5(email) is not a column, i put in the table BDM_TMP_MAIL_HARD  for make more understable the situation..

Comment: @leftjoin but why if i do the update without the function, it work ? normally it has not work also without the function if there is a problem of index

Comment: "if i do the update without the function" - you haven't shown an update, or how you are calling this function. I'd *guess* you're updating the table only for rows where this function returns 1, and without the `to_md5` part that never happens; and the table has rows locked by an uncommitted transaction in another session. But from the limited information you've included, that can only be a (fairly wild) guess.

Comment: Try to create index: CREATE INDEX idx_BDM_TMP_MAIL_HARD_fn ON BDM_TMP_MAIL_HARD (to_md5(email));

Comment: @AlexPoole the update is something like this: 

 update MY_TABLE set MATCH = 1 where lower(emailMD5) in 
 (select uoptima.to_md5(lower(EMAIL)) from optima.BDM_TMP_MAIL_HARD where EMAIL is not null) and emailMD5 is not null;

When i try this "manually", it work. There aren't row locked

Comment: I don't see how that relates to the function you've shown. Please edit the question to show exactly what you are doing. And if it works manually, is that happening in the same session where it appears to hang; if not have you committed/rolled back the manual attempt?

Comment: the update prouve me that there is no problem in my custom function **to_md5**, and there is not session in process

the problem is that i wait more of 5 h after the execution of the function (with no end), when with this update i do this in 5 minute

Comment: You still haven't shown how you are using/calling your `FILTRE_V1_MARKET_OP_MD5` function. (The goto into your function isn't needed, the argument should - presumably - be varchar2 not varchar, and it isn't doing the `lower(email)` part of your manual update; but none of that looks relevant. Have you checked for locks or are you just assuming there are none?)

Comment: i ve updated the question, i add how i call FILTRE_V1_MARKET_OP_MD5.

Yes i'm check that but there is nothing !

Comment: What is the purpose of `GOTO FIN`? The `GOTO` was used in 1970's nowadays it is a "no go"

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i can delete the GOTO, but the result not change...the problem is still here

Comment: I am still not clear what works and what does not. Is the problem that the FILTRE_V1_MARKET_OP_MD5 function never ends when the query inside it contains `and optima.to_md5(email) = mail_filtre`, or an update that calls some version of the function never ends? What is the session waiting on when this is happening? How long does the count take and how often is it called?

Answer (score 0):

Is `optima.to_md5(email)` a custom function you have written to generate an MD5 hash? If you are on Oracle 12c or higher, it would be better to use the [STANDARD_HASH](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions183.htm#SQLRF55647) function to generate the MD5 hash like this `STANDARD_HASH(email, 'MD5')`.

Comment: yes, it s a custom function that in every moment work, but not work in a function. 

The version of my oracle is 11.2, so i can't use this function.

Answer (score 0):

The dbms_obfuscation_toolkit is deprecated  after 11G so if you ever upgrade your backing yourself into a corner.

MD5 has been cryptographically broken and considered insecure.

You should be using DBMS_CRYPTO:

```
select rawtohex(
   DBMS_CRYPTO.Hash (
       UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ('foo', 'AL32UTF8'),  2)
    ) from dual;

Output:

ACBD18DB4CC2F85CEDEF654FCCC4A4D8
```

Here is a SHA512 function that I use to generate a hash KEY. Note if you are storing the value it should be in a column defined as RAW.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION HASH_SHA512 (
    psINPUT IN VARCHAR2
    ) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    rHash RAW (512);
    BEGIN
    rHash := DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH (TO_CLOB (psINPUT), 
dbms_crypto.HASH_SH512);
    RETURN (LOWER (RAWTOHEX (rHash)));
    END HASH_SHA512;
/

SELECT HASH_SHA512('This is a SHA512 output') from dual

aae656dfa520d7609f45de886f8f677ea2fdebb88400c5c3d6e8412c221c99944c42d167f6b3401c12a9636ea6121ae610861b1e3340a0ddba7e0ea096a64f75
```